# Only mpv player plays video

Tags: release-loki, videos, video-player

Default elementary video player (as well as for example Cinema Player) stopped playing videos. Ths sound works, but there is no video (its black). Doesn't matter which type of video I play.
Only mpv plays both video and it's sound.
What went wrong in my system?
Where to start some troubleshooting?

My system:

```
inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: iBiedak Kernel: 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0) Desktop: Gnome  (Gtk 3.18.9)
           Distro: elementary 0.4.1 loki
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: C460 v: Lenovo Product
           Mobo: LENOVO model: SHARKBAY v: 31900006 STD Bios: LENOVO v: IMKT23AUS date: 05/18/2016
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4130T (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 11572
           clock speeds: max: 2900 MHz 1: 2893 MHz 2: 2893 MHz 3: 2893 MHz 4: 2893 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.59hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-36-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 05:00.0
           IF: enp5s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8188ee port: c000 bus-ID: 06:00.0
           IF: wlp6s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (39.3% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000DM003 size: 1000.2GB temp: 34C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 902G used: 352G (42%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 16.78GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 198 Uptime: 17 min Memory: 1570.2/7890.0MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've had this issue before when I was using an Nvidia card. The solution for me was (ensuring your graphics drivers are installed and up to date (this can be done from within the AppCenter, in the 'Updates' tab)) installing ffmpeg and the gstreamer packages. `sudo apt install ffmpeg gstreamer1*`. Let me know if this works for you, I hope it does, otherwise, this must be something else.

Comment: THX man, this worked!