# Video execution lag

Tags: release-juno, videos, video-player

When using *io.elementary.videos*, *cinema* (from the store), or *totem* (from gnome) (gui)applications, after a while, the video stops while the audio continue his execution.

I used *.mp4* and *.mkv* videos and codec *gstreamer*.

My pc is a *Dell inspiron 7559* (laptop) with *Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz*, *Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530* and *NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]* (with propietary drivers).

It has a 4k screen.

Someone knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: without detailed information... there's nothing to answer. If you want an answer based on your question, I should say just stop watching videos.

Comment: maybe is more helpful to say what kind of information do you need, isn't it?

Comment: I have the same issue and it's pretty much generic. Anything (video) i start playing just lags. I have a intel video card. Works perfectly with many other Linux distros, including Ubuntu, but not Elementary.
Sebastian... be nice.

Comment: This isn't a place to be nice, just to answer questions. And a poor question deserves that kind of answer. What kind of information? Which program did you use? which video? which codec? did you use the command line or directly through the gui? are you comfortable using the command line? you video card information? if it's a laptop, which brand and model? did you installed a third party driver?... etc. Quoting: "Be specific

If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."

Comment: Sebastian, yes it is a place to be nice. According to the Code of Conduct: "Be kind and friendly. ",  and "If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming."

Comment: I was friendly, but not nice. I also gave him feedback and an answer based on his question. And I used the comments section for it because I expect him to give us information. I'm not the only one who have to read the Code, in fact the guidelines for questions are pretty clear. I didn't sent him to the old "read the manual", I just think this website and all of us (the ones who try to help answering) deserve respect in the form of a well written question. If you don't enforce this, then why we have the downvote as part of the system to "punish" bad questions.

Comment: your question is too generic, a generic answer would be: install the latest version of your video drivers. (It's like someone asks: my car stopped, how can I fix it?) It could be helpful if you could tell us what hardware you have. (video card, cpu, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

### First

Let's check if you have Nvidia drivers installed

**Install:**

`$ sudo apt install software-properties-gtk software-properties-common`

**Open:**

`$ software-properties-gtk`

**Choose** the tab `Additional Drivers`

**Wait** for the  loading list, and then **you should see the installed drivers**.

[image]

If you don't see any NVIDIA proprietary driver in the list, you need to install them

If you see them, just choose it and then reboot to start clean

---

To install the driver

**Use the command:**

`$ sudo ubuntu-drivers list`

You should get something like this (probably different version numbers):

```
nvidia-304
nvidia-340
intel-microcode
nvidia-367
```

**Install** `nvidia-367` (or the version you want/need, and could be different)

`$ sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-settings`

Then and again you have to choose the driver

**Open:**

`$ software-properties-gtk`

**Choose** the tab `Additional Drivers`

**Wait** for the  loading list, and then **you should see the installed drivers**.

[image]

Just choose the driver in the list and then reboot to start clean

ref: https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/d3344422ee6d334f284425b558dc572c

Now, after reboot, **open** `$ nvidia-settings`

**Look after** an entry named `PRIME Profiles`, **select** it and then **choose** the NVIDIA GPU

[image]

**Reboot** again

Now try open a video

Use `mpv` (If you don't have it install it with `sudo apt install mpv`)

Play the video with the command:

`mpv -v filename.mp4` (or mkv,avi, etc)

In case the error continues, just copy and paste the text in the terminal. It will be a lot because of the `-v` flag.

---

### Additional Info

You can also check and change PRIME using a command

**Install:**

`$ sudo apt install nvidia-prime`

**To check**

`$ sudo prime-select query`

**To select Intel GPU as PRIME**

`$ sudo prime-select intel`

**To select NVIDIA GPU as PRIME**

`$ sudo prime-select nvidia`

ref: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu

---

### Also for future reference in case the answer doesn't work

Run

`sudo lshw -sanitize -class system,processor,display,multimedia`

copy the output and paste it here editing your own post

Comment: with mpv only the video works without the need of the nvidia card.

Comment: check this...the same issue than you and a NVIDIA card without the drivers installed/updated https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/15046/14940. If you want to resolve te issue follow the steps, If not then just use mpv

Comment: I already installed Nvidia driver (but i selected intel with prime to save battery), and I had already installed both ffmpeg and all the gstreamer packages. But the problem is still there...maybe I should report it as a bug

Comment: Without a proper log from you and only taking your word of what is happening, yes you should report it as a bug. https://github.com/elementary/videos/issues https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/totem . At least you can play videos through mpv (fyi my main video player)